# TextField `title` is never shown on iOS if `prompt` is provided?

Tags: ios, swift, macos, swiftui, textfield

## Scenario

I have a multiplatform app written in SwiftUI. I want to share as much code between iOS and macOS as possible.

I have not been able to display both `title` and `prompt` of a TextField on iOS. When wrapped in a [`Form`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/form), both are displayed on **macOS** (provided that we use the `TextField` initializer passing both a `title` and a `prompt` of course), but never on iOS.

[Documentation states](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/textfield):

> You can set an explicit prompt on the text field to guide users on what text they should provide. Each text field style determines where and when the text field uses a prompt and label. For example, a form on macOS always places the label at the leading edge of the field and uses a prompt, when available, as placeholder text within the field itself. **In the same context on iOS, the text field uses either the prompt or label as placeholder text, depending on whether the initializer provided a prompt.**

### iOS

#### Screenshot

[image: ios]

#### Code

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var text1 = ""
    @State var text2 = ""
    @State var text3 = ""
    var body: some View {
        Form {
            TextField("T1", text: $text1, prompt: Text("P1"))
            TextField(text: $text2, prompt: Text("P2")) {
                Text("T2")
            }
            TextField("T3", text: $text3)
            
            Text("iOS: `title` \"T1\" & \"T2\" is never shown, \"P1\", \"P2\" & \"T3\" is shown when fields are empty.")
        }.padding()
    }
}
```

### macOS

#### Screenshot

[image: macOS]

#### Code

Code is identical....

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var text1 = ""
    @State var text2 = ""
    @State var text3 = ""
    var body: some View {
        Form {
            TextField("T1", text: $text1, prompt: Text("P1"))
            TextField(text: $text2, prompt: Text("P2")) {
                Text("T2")
            }
            TextField("T3", text: $text3)
            
            Text("macOS: `title` \"T1\", \"T2\" & \"T3\" are always shown, \"P1\", \"P2\" are shown when fields are empty.")
        }.padding()
    }
}
```

## Problem

The [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/textfield) shows an example which uses the prompt `"Required"` for a password field. This is extremely confusing when **only** this `prompt` is shown and never the `title` "Password"` on iOS. Because the user does not know what she is inputting... Just that she is inputting something that is required.

## Question

How can I avoid `prompt` hiding `title` on iOS, while still leverage them on macOS? Feels like I have to write my own TextField view impl checking if platform is macOS then do nothing, otherwise if iOS add a manual `title` view and wrap them in a HStack/VStack?

What am I missing?

Comment: The documentation states that `prompt` is shown if it is provided, otherwise `title` is shown. In other words, if you provide a value for `prompt` then `title` will never be shown on ios.  When I use a text field on ios I use an additional `Label` if the placeholder isn't sufficient.

Comment: Right, will edit my question, I wonder how I can leverage the `prompt` and `title` on macOS while not hiding the `title` with the `prompt` on iOS

Comment: I think you would need to just have conditional code that adds a label on ios.  You could easily create a `LabelledTextField` `View` that adds the `Label` when required

Comment: @Paulw11 yupp that is my conclusion too, feels like it is the best solution. Just thought maybe I missed something and there was some setup which could let me avoid having to wrap the TextField...

Comment: From what I understand from the doc is that on iOS the prompt is set in place of the placeholder not as label (= for lacOS). That is quite strange. So the best would be to add a label that exists only for iOS.